# Xcode 4.5 doesn't launch iOS application in simulator or mac app when running/debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, debugging

Having a strange issue with XCode 4.5 on OSX 10.8.2.

When I run an application on the mac, it doesn't launch and I get the following error in console consistently.

```
10/01/2013 17:26:26.478 Xcode[7884]: ERROR: Failed to create an alert for ID "enabled" based on defaults: 1
```

When I run an iPad/iPhone app, the simulator launches, but the app just shows a blank screen. I thought there was an issue with my apps (although very unlikely) so attempted to create a vanilla mac app and iOS app. Both experience the same issues. Running/Debugging any iPad project directly on the iPad through Xcode works however.

I've attempted to:

- Delete everything in ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/
- Delete the Xcode app and download it again from the AppStore
- Delete all of my Xcode preferences

Xcode Build and stop buttons also become unresponsive so I have to force quit xcode to try again.

Nothing seems to be working, Xcode works fine however on my mac pro at work and all projects build just fine! Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, setting the debugger to GDB instead of LLDB seems to have fixed this. It would however be good to get an answer as to why LLDB doesn't work as the default debugger and what's changed in xcode to make it no longer work as expected.